# Google Visualization API : Line Chart - Hide negative values in Y-axis

Tags: google-visualization

I use Google Visualization API to plot Line Chart. Here are the codes:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
function drawCharts() {
    // Total Coupon View
    var data_total_users = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data_total_users.addColumn('string', 'Total Users');
    data_total_users.addColumn('number', 'User Count');

    data_total_users.addRows(7);
    data_total_users.setValue(0, 0, 'Sunday');
    data_total_users.setValue(0, 1, 10);
    data_total_users.setValue(1, 0, 'Monday');
    data_total_users.setValue(1, 1, 4);
    data_total_users.setValue(2, 0, 'Tuesday');
    data_total_users.setValue(2, 1, 3);
    data_total_users.setValue(3, 0, 'Wednesday');
    data_total_users.setValue(3, 1, 7);
    data_total_users.setValue(4, 0, 'Thursday');
    data_total_users.setValue(4, 1, 8);
    data_total_users.setValue(5, 0, 'Friday');
    data_total_users.setValue(5, 1, 10);
    data_total_users.setValue(6, 0, 'Saturday');
    data_total_users.setValue(6, 1, 10);
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_users_total'));
    chart.draw(data_total_users, {width: 1000, height: 400, title: '', hAxis: {title: ''}});
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

**Question is**: How can I remove the -0.5, -1.0 ? Also, I would like to have integers (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3, ...) in Y-axis. Which parameter should I add?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your chart.draw call, add:
vAxis:{viewWindow: {min: 0}}

Comment: For GoogleVisualr::Interactive::LineChart, It's not working. Please let me know if anybody have solution. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work for a LineChart as mentioned above. Looks like you have to set a max value as mentioned in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37482770/6619548

Answer (score 4):

if set options vAxis: {viewWindow: {min: 0}} did not work try to set vAxis:{viewWindow: {min: 0, max: 10}}

Comment: This does work for a LineChart but it would be a lot better if you didn't have to set a max value. In my case I know that there will never be any values less than 0, but I don't know what the max is. It means having to loop through the dataset to check what the max value actually is so you don't crop any values off.